# Timepicker: Create a date object

Tags: java, android, date, android-timepicker

I have a `timepicker` and on clicking on it I want to get the current time and store it. I am using a class to store a bunch of info and I am using a date object to store the time (that comes closest when it comes to `date` and `time`. I am unaware of any other data structure that I can use)

On using the `getCurrentHour()` and the `getCurrrentMinute()` methods I get two `integers` giving me hour and the minute selected by the user. I want to convert these two integers into a `date` object or at least store this data in some kind of a time format which is producible and can be tinkered with later.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Calendar object:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
Date desiredDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: I edited the question to give you more clarity about the `getCurrentHour()` and the `getCurrentMinute()` methods. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for?  The only native object for storing time is the Date object.  You could import a 3rd party library like http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ and have a LocalTime object created from that on click.  If you are worried about comparing times and things of that nature in the future, just adjust the date so it's always the same date and then the times will be comparable with the native methods.  If you are wanting to store it in an SQLLite database, you'd store it as a long (desiredDate.getTime())